How to set up regression testing in Postman to compare JSON structures while ignoring specific values?
To load iterations from a CSV file for further testing, this script should be used.
// Load CSV data into an object
let csvData = pm.iterationData.toObject();

// Remove empty or null fields from CSV data
for (let key in csvData) {
    if (csvData[key] === "" || csvData[key] === null) {
        delete csvData[key];
    }
}

// Create request body
let requestBody = {
    a: csvData.a,
    // Internal structure, if needed
};

// Function to remove undefined fields from an object
function removeEmptyFields(obj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => value !== undefined ? value : undefined));
}

// Clean the request body to remove undefined values
requestBody = removeEmptyFields(requestBody);

// Set cleaned CSV data and request body as environment variables in Postman
pm.environment.set("csvData", JSON.stringify(csvData));
pm.environment.set("requestBody", JSON.stringify(requestBody, null, 2));

// Log cleaned CSV data and request body for debugging
console.log(csvData);
console.log(requestBody);`

To set up regression testing in Postman to compare JSON structures while ignoring specific values, you can use a custom script in the Tests section. Here's a simplified explanation of the key components and steps involved:
1.Configuration Object: Define a configuration object to specify which fields, paths, or field types should be ignored during the comparison. This allows you to customize the behavior of the test.
 const config = {
        ignoredFields: [], // Fields to ignore during comparison
        ignoredPaths: [], // Specific paths to ignore
        ignoredFieldTypes: [], // Field types to ignore
        fieldsToClean: [], // Fields where dynamic content should be removed before comparison
    };

2.Load Expected Result: Retrieve the expected result from an environment variable or another source, and parse it into a JSON object.

    let csvData = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("csvData"));
    let expectedResultStr = csvData.ExpRes;
    if (typeof expectedResultStr === 'string') {
        expectedResultStr = expectedResultStr.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');
    }
    let expectedResult = JSON.parse(expectedResultStr);

3.Comparison Logic: Implement a function to compare the actual response JSON with the expected result, taking into account the ignored fields and dynamic content.

    function compareObjects(obj1, obj2, path = '') {
        let differences = [];
        const keys = new Set([...Object.keys(obj1 || {}), ...Object.keys(obj2 || {})]);

        keys.forEach(key => {
            const currentPath = path ? `${path}.${key}` : key;
            const val1 = obj1 ? obj1[key] : undefined;
            const val2 = obj2 ? obj2[key] : undefined;

            if (config.ignoredFields.includes(key)) return;

            if (val1 !== val2) {
                differences.push(`Mismatch at '${currentPath}': expected '${val2}', got '${val1}'`);
            }
        });

        return differences;
    }
4.Test Execution: Use Postman's pm.test function to execute the comparison and log any differences.

    pm.test("Response matches expected result (excluding ignored fields)", function () {
        const response = pm.response.json();
        const differences = compareObjects(response, expectedResult);
        if (differences.length > 0) {
            console.log("Differences found:\n" + differences.join('\n'));
        }
        pm.expect(differences.length, differences.join('\n')).to.equal(0);
    });

5.Error Handling: Include error handling to manage JSON parsing errors or undefined expected results.

    try {
        // Parsing and comparison logic
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error parsing JSON: ", e);
        pm.test("Error parsing JSON", function () {
            pm.expect.fail(`Error parsing JSON: ${e.message}`);
        });
    }



This setup allows you to perform regression testing by comparing JSON structures while ignoring specified fields or dynamic content, ensuring that only relevant differences are flagged.
For more detailed information and step-by-step instructions on how to accomplish this, please visit our repository where everything is thoroughly explained: https://github.com/greatFU/Postman-Automation-Testing.git.
I am setting up regression testing in Postman to compare JSON responses with expected results stored in a CSV file. My goal is to dynamically load expected results from the CSV, parse them into JSON, and compare them with actual API responses while ignoring specific fields.
The script includes logic to handle CSV data, such as cleaning dynamic fields and configuring ignored paths for comparison. Despite following these steps, I'm encountering issues with [specific problem, e.g., CSV parsing, path handling, or unexpected comparison results].

I had this question, found the solution myself, and attempted to share it by posting the question and answering it. It seems I might have done this in the wrong section.
